# BotFramework Action does not rendered as Buttons (empty) in Facebook Messenger and Telegram

Tags: c#, bots, telegram-bot, facebook-messenger, botframework

I'm trying Microsoft Bot Connector action to be rendered as Buttons in Facebook Messenger but it is not being rendered as expected. In fact the messenger does not display anything. While Testing on the BotFramework Emulator only display the .Text property but does not display buttons as well.

```
class myFactory
{

public static IForm<myButton> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<myButton>()
           .Message("Welcome to my test Button!")
           .OnCompletionAsync(async (context, myButton) =>
           {
               var reply = context.MakeMessage();
               reply.Text = "Test actions";
               reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

               var actions = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action>();

               actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action() { Title = "button1", Message = "message1", Url = "http://google.com" });
               actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action() { Title = "button2", Message = "message2", Url = "http://google.com" });
               actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action() { Title = "button3", Message = "message3", Url = "http://google.com" });

               Attachment at = new Attachment();
                   at.Title = "Choose One:";
                   at.Actions = actions;
                   at.ContentType = "template";
                   at.Text = "Text choose";
                   at.TitleLink = "http://www.google.com";
                   at.ContentUrl = "http://msdn.microsoft.com";

                   reply.Attachments.Add(at);

                    await context.PostAsync(reply);
           })
           .Build();
    }
};
```

Comment: After testing rigorously. I found out that Buttons works only in Web Facebook messages and not in mobile facebook messenger app. Telegram does not also display the buttons I wanted. The solution I am thinking now is to check what channel my bot is running in order to render appropriate replies.

Comment: Buttons should work universally across all Facebook messenger clients, kik, and telegram. Can it be that you have an old version of fb messenger app that doesn't have support for buttons and carousel? I generate buttons in my bot using `Actions` and rely on connector to downgrade them to text options for channels that don't have button support.

Comment: @ShahinShayandeh Yes.you are correct I forgot to mention I'm running it on windows phone but it works correctly using UWP desktop version of Messenger as well as android messenger version. Please add your comment as answer so I can flag it as correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've not worked with Telegram but for Facebook action buttons you only need to supply the Message or the Url, not both. If the Url property is supplied then the action button will link out to that url but when the Message is supplied then when clicked that text will be sent to your bot as if the user had typed it.

Also, the ContentType and ContentUrl in the Attachment might be causing problems. The ContentUrl, if supplied, should point to an image or video and then the ContentType should be "image" or "video". You do not need to specify "template", the Bot Connector does that for you. Try something like:

```
var reply = context.MakeMessage();
reply.Text = "Test actions";
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

var actions = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action>();

actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action() { Title = "button1", Message = "message1" });
actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action() { Title = "button2", Url = "http://bing.com" });
actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action() { Title = "button3", Message = "message3" });

Attachment at = new Attachment();
at.Title = "Choose One:";
at.Actions = actions;

reply.Attachments.Add(at);
```

Comment: Sorry bout the url and contentType it was included out of experimenting what portions will give the output I wanted. Anyway I will try your answer and will give you feedback.

Comment: Hi, I just found out that the buttons I'm expecting is working on web Facebook messages and not working in mobile facebook messenger. using the code I posted. I really appreciate your help but I cannot accept it as an answer. Please reply a comment here so I can so I can vote up your answer, Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Buttons should work universally across all Facebook messenger clients, kik, and telegram. I guess you are using an older version of Facebook messenger app that doesn't have support for buttons and carousel. I generate buttons in my bot using Actions and rely on connector to downgrade them to text options for channels that don't have button support. Here is an example of [a bot with attachments](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/EchoBot/EchoAttachmentDialog.cs) that works with facebook.

Answer (score 0):

in the newest version of botbuilder (v1.2.3), by default, prompt will be generated as selectable buttons in supported chat platforms (for example: telegram, facebook).

**Reference:** https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/FormFlow/FormDialog.cs

**Relevant code:**

```
if (prompt != null)
{
    var msg = context.MakeMessage();
    msg.Text = prompt.Prompt;
    msg.Attachments = prompt.Buttons.GenerateAttachments();
    await context.PostAsync(msg);
}
return prompt;
```